# Django, Nginx, Gunicorn. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, django

Работаю с данной статьёй - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-a-gunicorn-systemd-service-file

пишу команду - sudo systemctl restart nginx
мне выдаёт сообщение - sudo: unable to resolve host giver.local

Как быть?

Comment: Скорее всего Вы базу данных пытаетесь подключить с неведомого хоста. Дайте сюда содерживое переменной DATABASES из settings.py

Comment: `'''
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


'''



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'giver',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '99999',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        }
    }

}
`
Прошу Вас

Comment: Это точно локальный конфиг ?

Comment: Что то странное. В руководстве говорится про __postgre__, а тут mysql, да еще и без хоста...